# AttributeError module 'select' has no attribute 'poll'

Tags: python, github, attributeerror

May I ask for some help? I am attempting to clone an existing GitHub project and am struggling to identify what I could be doing wrong.  The project is a pluggable SXM music player written in Python ( https://github.com/AngellusMortis/sxm-player), that I've cloned and attempted to run through Visual Studio Code (v1.65.2).  Upon executing the project, **the code returns an error - "Exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'select' has no attribute 'poll'"**. Little doubt that I must be doing something incorrectly - but to this point, I haven't been able to identify what I need to do differently to get it to run properly.  My sincerest apologies for needing to ask this probably simple question on this forum, but I know that this would be the place to find the experience to get this package up and running and **any assistance would be greatly appreciated**.

Here is the traceback for the error message:

```
File "C:\GitHub\sxm-player\sxm_player\utils.py", line 173, in FFmpeg
    _stderr_poll: Optional[select.poll] = None
File "C:\GitHub\sxm-player\sxm_player\utils.py", line 169, in <module>
    class FFmpeg:
File "C:\GitHub\sxm-player\sxm_player\runner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from sxm_player.utils import configure_root_logger
File "C:\GitHub\sxm-player\sxm_player\handlers.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sxm_player.runner import Runner, Worker
File "C:\GitHub\sxm-player\sxm_player\cli.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sxm_player import handlers
File "C:\GitHub\sxm-player\sxm_player\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sxm_player.cli import main
```

Answer (score 0):

From the module "select":
*** IMPORTANT NOTICE *** On Windows, only sockets are supported; on Unix, all file descriptors.

The same module will work on WSL. You can install the WSL extension on Visual Studio Code and run your code there:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl